# What is a good access time to a database (SQL)?

Tags: sql, database

Hey.. i wanna know which time is  a good accesstime, because i'm searching for a good sql database and hsqldb says their accesstime is **12ms**... <-- good?

Comment: What is this "accesstime" metric encompassing? Are they talking just connecting to the database? Returning results? If you have a link to where this 12ms number is specified, that might help.

Comment: haha 0ms... very funny but nonsense

@arcain: to return results

Answer (score 1):

I think it would depend on your needs. Is it for a web server or a desktop application? The amount of data is also important, because reading lots of small records will perform differently than reading a few large records. Access time is also based upon your hardware, software and maybe even some other factors.
For example, you can use a database with lightning-fast access, but if your users need to connect to it over a 5 megabit VPN connection, passing through three different proxies and with trafic world-wide, your database would then just be a waste of power.
Basically, it's a marketing thing that they're claiming. It's a good product but don't just focus on access time. Make sure you also look at your other needs. Another system might just perform better, even if it has a slower acess time, because it is more optimized in reading it's indices and stuff.
So, what do you want, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think access time tells you anything, really. If you have slow or incorrectly configured storage, then this access time metric will be dwarfed by how much time is spent on waits and split I/Os.  Network latency is also a factor, since I'm guessing you probably won't want to have your code on the same machine as your database, and you will most likely have a few network devices you'll need to traverse in your production environment.

In my experience, all the database platforms these days will all perform adequately if configured correctly and paired with a complementary application. Pick the DBMS that best fits your requirements, follow the best practices for configuration of the DBMS on your hardware, and you should be please with the outcome.

Comment: If you are planning on having your application installed alongside the DBMS on a workstation, then many of the latency factors I mentioned will be moot, or at least equalized.

Check out this [H2][1] database performance page. It shows higher performance statistics than hsqldb. You may also consider SQLite which is extremely fast and does not require its own process, however it is written in C and not a Java.


  [1]: http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html

Comment: If you have the time, I'd encourage you to benchmark H2, hsqldb, and SQLite with loads that simulate your application in an environment that mimics where your app will be deployed. Only that will really tell you which one will work better *with your app.* Another interesting comparison (of features, not performance characteristics) is here: http://3rdstage.blogspot.com/2009/03/comparion-of-hsqldb-h2-sqlite.html